# installing wx gizmos for python on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

I've installed wx for python on windows with 
pip install wxpython
The python script I'm using tries to import wx.gizmos. The program fails there with error "No module names gizmos". So i've tried to install it with
pip install gizmos,
pip install wxgizmos,
pip install wx.gizmos,
pip install wxpython.gizmos,
pip install wxpythongizmos.
Error is "No matching distribution found for..."
I've been to https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/main.html and it appears gizmos is not there and so can't be used but the python script needs it.
Is there a way of installing this or a way arond this ?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled python wx using: 
pip uninstall wxpython.
and reinstalled it from here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.9.5.0/wxPython2.9-win64-2.9.5.0-py27.exe/download